# Can two spells with different types of components be cast in the same action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components

Would someone who is casting something with a Somatic and Material component, say Minor Illusion, also be able to cast something with only a Verbal component, say Thaumaturgy, in the same action? I'm making a character who will be casting these cantrips on a regular basis for cosmetic changes, and want to know if there is an official ruling on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No, the whole action is needed to cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action

*[Minor illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion)* and *[thaumaturgy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thaumaturgy)* both have a casting time of 1 action.

There is nothing in the [rules for casting spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) that suggests that you can cast two spells at once with one action.

If you use your action to cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action, you cannot cast another spell with a casting time of one action unless you have another action (such as via the fighter's [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ActionSurge-193)), or unless you can modify the casting time (such as via the sorcerer's [Quickened Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372)), regardless of each spell's components.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  So a Divine Soul Sorcerer who applied Quickened Spell to one of them would be able to do it.  Granted, poor use of Sorcery points, but possible.  Otherwise it is two separate actions, thus two separate turns.

Comment: @TheFoxfiend It's also worth noting that Quickened Spell is just as happy casting two spells that require the full VSM - you can definitely flavour that as "casting two spells at the same time because the components don't overlap" in many cases, but mechanically it's just casting them sequentially, and there's no benefit from avoiding that overlap.

Answer (score 2):

“Cosmetic changes” seems like it will usually be an *outside-of-combat* concern, in which case your concern shouldn’t be much of an issue.

The action economy of spell casting times is mostly a concern in combat. In combat, your action can be used to cast at most one spell with a casting time of 1 action.

Outside of combat, the rigid structure of initiative and action economies usually matters little, so you could easily cast multiple spells in succession with little issue, as long as concentration rules are observed:

> You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

Now if you really want to cast *thaumaturgy* and *minor illusion* in a single turn, the sorcerer metamagic *quickened spell* has what you need:

> When you cast a spell that has a casting time of 1 action, you can spend 2 sorcery points to change the casting time to 1 bonus action for this casting.

The Divine Soul Sorcerer allows you to access *thaumaturgy* as a sorcerer, so this is a feasible option for what you wish to achieve.

Comment: On the note of Thaumaturgy only appearing on the cleric spell list, Divine Soul Sorcerer.

Comment: Are you playing a divine soul sorcerer?

Comment: Good point that it doesn't matter out of combat.